# Where can I find drawings of a mobile home's construction?

Tags: repair, framing

I bought my very first trailer/mobile home last August. I've never lived in one, never spent significant time in one, know less than nothing about them. That said, I have a doublewide 90 Commodore. Not sure of the exact model. I'd just like to find some information on how trailers are made, what's behind the walls, etc.

My entire 20 year construction background is on wood-studded homes. I'm completely out of my element. I've checked the homeowner's manual and installation manuals, Googled, checked YouTube, but nothing tells me what's behind the walls, without having to take them all down. **I would like, at the very least, information on stud types and locations. Is it not standard to have them set 18"OC?**  I'm really clueless here. Any help whatsoever would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SE. You ask many questions in your post. Our format, being a Q&Q type site, works best when you ask one specific question. It's hard to select and upvote answers when you spread things so thin. Please edit to simplify and clarify, and ask additional, separate questions if you like.

Comment: oh sorry! i tend to rush everything together. thank you!

Comment: Does the structure more closely resemble a [travel trailer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_trailer), or a permanent structure?   The term "*trailer/mobile home*" covers a large diverse group of structures.

Comment: Where did you get 18" o.c.? I'd expect 16, or maybe 24.

Comment: it's a (mostly) permanently parked trailer with skirting, sorry. It fully resembles a home, and not a trailer.

Comment: Looking at there web site you have a modular. "The term ‘mobile home' refers to factory homes built prior to 1976."  Is it a 1990 model commodore double wide?